# Connect / Sync a folder to another folder with a correct path

Tags: linux, server, synchronization, command, symlink

I have 2 Frameworks on my Virtual Server, both have a **plugins folder** and **Framework A** has some plugins which also need to be used in **Framework B**.

I need a connection from **Framework B plugin folder** to **Framework A plugin folder**. But it has to still work correctly if for example a file in Framework B uses the path to it's own plugins folder it should not result in an error because it's actually empty.

**Do I need symlink, rsync or something else?**

/html/framework_a/plugins/...
/html/framework_b/plugins/

Comment: You want `/html/framework_b/plugins/` to contain it's own files + the files from `/html/framework_a/plugins/` ?  Since plugins exists in both,  you cannot use a link on plugins.  You could write a script to link every file from `/html/framework_a/plugins/` into `/html/framework_b/plugins/` **if** there is not already a file with that name.

Comment: @Nic3500 no Framework B is not allowed to have its own files, it only needs the plugins Framework A has. How would I write that  script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok based on your comment, Framework B must have all the files from Framedwork A, and nothing more.  Then the solution is quite simple.  You only have to link the entire directory.

Therefore:

```
$ cd /html/framework_b
$ mv plugins plugins-backup
$ ln -s /html/framework_a/plugins ./plugins
```

This will create a softlink, so if you do `cd /html/framework_b/plugins` you will see the same files as in `/html/framework_a/plugins`.